# sql: Flag the next few rows of a column based on another column value

Tags: mysql, teradata

This is my raw table:

```
row itm wk  ft  sd
1   i1  w1  0   0
2   i1  w2  1   0
3   i1  w3  1   0
4   i1  w4  1   0
5   i1  w5  0   1
6   i1  w6  0   1
7   i1  w7  0   0
8   i1  w8  0   0
----------
9   i2  w1  0   0
10  i2  w2  0   0
11  i2  w3  1   0
12  i2  w4  1   0
13  i2  w5  0   1
14  i2  w6  0   1
15  i2  w7  0   0
16  i2  w8  0   0
```

---

I want to flag "sd" column as 1 for the next two rows(weeks) from the row were the "ft" column has changed its state from 1 to 0 for each item.

for example :-
In the above dataset there are two items 'i1' and 'i2' and each item has data for eight weeks(w1-w8) and "ft" column will have values(1 or 0) for each week but in for the eight weeks the ft column for a item will be made one for weeks greater than one.

now i want to flag the "sd" column for the next two rows from the point where the "ft" flag changed its value from 1 to 0 for each item.

like in the above dataset for item "i1", "sd" is 1 for row no: 5 and 6 
and for "i2", sd is 1 for row no:13 and 14

Comment: What's you actual DBMS, `mysql` or `teradata`?

Answer (score 1):

For Teradata you can apply a Windowed Aggregate Function. This should return the correct result for your example, I don't know if there are any additional rules:

```
case
  when max(ft) -- look for a 1 in the two weeks before the current week
       over (partition by itm order by wk 
             rows between 2 preceding and 1 preceding) = 1
   and ft = 0  -- current value must be zero
  then 1 
  else 0
end
```

Comment: Thank you . It was very helpful.